# "Eis" instead of "es" in the crop b'racha in the Amida

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, chabad, vowels-nekudot

[The ninth *b'racha* of the *amida*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Weekday_Shacharit%2C_Amidah?lang=he) begins with the words

> בָּרֵךְ עָלֵינוּ ה' אֱ-לֹהֵינוּ
> **אֶת** הַשָּׁנָה הַזֹּאת
> **וְאֶת** כָּל מִינֵי תְּבוּאָתָהּ לְטוֹבָה

where both את are vocalized with *segol* (three triangular dots).

I have heard multiple *sh'lichei tzibur* at a Lubavitch establishment pronounce the second "אֶת" as "eis" (or [eɪs]). So I consulted two of the most common Lubavitch-used *sidurim*, and indeed [it was printed that way](http://www.770live.com/en770/siddur/siddur.htm), contrary to every other paper *sidur* of various versions and traditions I've checked, which have them both as "es".

[Assuming the word is the accusative marker "את" and not the homonymous word for "with"] the vocalization might vary based on the following word if it is following [the Biblical pattern of vocalization](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/117._The_Direct_Subordination_of_the_Noun_to_the_Verb_as_Accusative_of_the_Object._The_Double_Accusative). If so, which of the rules of that system would make these two words come out differently?

Here are a pair provided by @paquda where the "את" is either connected to the next word by a "-" and "shortened" from its default state of "eis" to "es" or disconnected and left in its natural state of vocalization:

> Joined:
>
> כִּ֚י **אֶת־כׇּל־מַֽעֲשֶׂ֔ה** הָאֱלֹהִ֛ים יָבִ֥א בְמִשְׁפָּ֖ט עַ֣ל כׇּל־נֶעְלָ֑ם אִם־ט֖וֹב וְאִם־רָֽע׃
>
> Separate:
>
> וַיִּבְרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֔ים אֶת־הַתַּנִּינִ֖ם הַגְּדֹלִ֑ים **וְאֵ֣ת כׇּל־נֶ֣פֶשׁ** הַֽחַיָּ֣ה ׀ הָֽרֹמֶ֡שֶׂת אֲשֶׁר֩ שָׁרְצ֨וּ הַמַּ֜יִם לְמִֽינֵהֶ֗ם וְאֵ֨ת כׇּל־ע֤וֹף כָּנָף֙ לְמִינֵ֔הוּ וַיַּ֥רְא אֱלֹהִ֖ים כִּי־טֽוֹב׃

**Why does the second "את" have a *tzeirei* ([ei])?**

Comment: Maybe it's along the same lines as zeicher/zecher in Ashrei.

Comment: Probably related to [R' Shlomo Zalman Hanau](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1643/2), somehow.

Comment: In theory the _segol-tzeirei_ distinction is based on whether there was a _maqaf_ to join the את to the next word, or it got a _taam_ on its own right. Since for prayer texts we don't have such traditions, it is hard to find a solid reason for a similar choice.

Comment: @WAF Does my comment qualify for an answer?

Comment: @Kazi I think not. Even given it's hard to come up with or prove such rules, this text is seemingly deliberately different from all the others and is almost certainly based on a made up rule by the above-mentioned R Hanau. That'll be the answer, even if his rule is wrong/new/different/not convincing.

Comment: @ezra definitely not, that's just an old typo for a very specific local reason, not generalizable to other cases https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73236/759

Comment: BTW Heidenheim wrote tzeirei in the morning prayer at אתה הוא ה' אלקינו (...) ואת כל אשר בם. I could never ever figure out his reason. Same for _cholam_ and _kamatz_ choices.

Comment: I'm wondering if the vav added to ואת makes the word more likely to stand alone rather than be joined by a maqaf to the next word. E.g.,  שׁוֹמֵר יְהוָה אֶת כָּל אֹהֲבָיו וְאֵת כָּל הָרְשָׁעִים and וַיִּזְכֹּר אֱלֹהִים אֶת נֹחַ וְאֵת כָּל הַחַיָּה -- but wait, later in that same verse וְאֶת כָּל הַבְּהֵמָה אֲשֶׁר אִתּוֹ -- never mind.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Even within Tanach, whether there's a makaf or not depends on the tune.  https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.16.9?p2=Psalms.105.2

Comment: @Heshy Or the other way around?

Comment: "But even if it were I would expect both "אֶת הַשָּׁנָה" and "אֶת כָּל" to behave the same." Why?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות OK, good point. Maybe I assumed too strongly. They seem like similar enough phrases, but @ paquda's examples show that that is not enough to determine how they will behave on this particular variable.

Comment: @WAF I actually believe that it is the answer here.  Look through any passuk in the Torah with many את in it, and you will notice similar phrases with different vowelization.

Comment: It's still only half an answer @רבות since everyone else has "es" for both, so clearly someone is doing something deliberate. If you want to phrase it as why the difference between Nusachs instead of why the difference between es/eis in one Nusach, whatever.

Comment: Shouldn't we start with a question about the _magaf-segol_ vs. no _maqaf-tzeirei_ choice in the _Tanakh?_