# Is וּכְתַבְתָּ֛ם in Shema with Shva Na or Shva Nach

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

My daughter goes to a chabad school (nusach ari?) and has been taught in class that וּכְתַבְתָּ֛ם in the shema (end of first paragraph) is with a shvah na on the כְ. She also says it has the asterisk ontop of the chaf in her siddur.

However, I have only seen it in the siddurim (ashkenaz) with a shva nach (silent).

Is there a difference with this pronunciation between the different nusachot?

Comment: Very relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/why-so-many-vocalized-shvas-in-siddur-tehillat-hashem/

Comment: You can double check in tikkun tikorin that mark the difference between a sh'va na and a sh'va nach.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer ([as JoelK noted, see this one for more](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/why-so-many-vocalized-shvas-in-siddur-tehillat-hashem/)) -- disagreement among grammarians about cases like this. Listen to your favorite baal kriah read Exodus 7:29, about the frogs:

> וּבְכָה וּבְעַמְּךָ, וּבְכָל-עֲבָדֶיךָ

All three of those "vet"s are in that same gray zone.

As it was taught to me -- you can't start a word with two sh'vas, as you'd have a conflict between "first letter is always *na*" and "two sh'vas together? Second is *na*" So "v'b'cha" became "uvcha." However it would have been "**b**'cha", so some retain the na.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is based on the problem of whether the vav-hachibur
that is marked with a shuruk and pronounced like "oo" in look is
really a kubutz or a shuruk.
Since kubutz is (according to R' Eliyahu Bachur) 'A movement between a shuruk and a chirik'
and a t'nuaa k'tana (small movement) the rule will apply that if it's not emphasised
a sh'va after it will be nach, and vise versa with a t'nua g'dola like shuruk, where it will be na. The general consensus though is that the vav-hachibur shuruk is a shuruk,
so, unless the vav itself is emphasised, the sh'va after it will be na and not nach.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea! Since we don't know who any individual user is, we prefer to have posts with sources. Do you have a source for `the general consensus`? And what do you mean about an `emphasised` shuruk giving a nach?

Comment: @magicker72 the general consensus by Melamdim (teachers of young children). I also recall reading in Otzar Hachochma a book that deals with the sugia but I cannot recall which. But I'm certain that I'm citing correctly.

Comment: @magicker72 emphasised being that it has a Maarich on the letter.

Comment: It would be great if you could find that source again and [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/121860/edit) it into your answer, so others can verify your claims.